# Code for both static and dynamic polymorphism in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, crtp

Is there a way so that I can write code as the follows:

```
IConnection<Socket> s{Socket{...}}; // statically
Connection* c = new Socket{...};          //dynamically

// a heterogeneous list that require dynamically dispatch /existential type/ type erase
List<Connection*> l { new Socket{...}
, new MockSock{...}, new LocalDataBase{...}, ...}
```

I tried to implement class suitable for both dynamic and static polymorphism on a need-to-erase basis, i.e. only use dynamic polymorphism if i have to (heterogeneous list, e.g.). I write following code

```cpp
class Connection {
public:
Connection& operator=(Connection& c) = delete;
Connection(Connection& c) = delete;
Connection& operator=(Connection&& c) = delete;
Connection(Connection&& c) = delete;
virtual ~Connection() = 0;
virtual string Recv() = 0;
}

template<typename T>
class IConnection : Connection{
public:
inline T* dispatch(){
   return static_cast<T*>(this);
}
virtual string Recv() override{
    return dispatch()->Recv();
}
...
}
```

However, if i am to implement `class Socket :IConnection<Socket>`, then `Recv()` in `class Socket` would still be a dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Why do you need both ? Dynamic polymorphism seems to be the right fit for your needs.

Comment: It seems you use CRTP only to manually do what dynamic polymorphism already does for you in runtime, i.e. you only do dispatch types and forward member functions. Dynamic polymorphism already does that automatically. I'm pretty sure you don't need CRTP here, but maybe there are more in your case than shown in your question...

Comment: Assuming Socket::Recv is final, then the compiler will most likely be able to optimise away the dynamic dispatch in that case. You can explicitly use the `final` keyword to more or less make sure that happens.

Comment: You can't do `Connection c{Socket{}};` because polymorphism works through pointers or references (and `Connection` is abstract so you can't instantiate it). What you can do instead is `Connection * c = new Socket{};`, for example.

Comment: Judging from this question and one of the previous questions, you might be misunderstanding the purpose of CRTP. It is completely different from that of dynamic inheritance-cum-virtual-dispatch polymorphism. CRTP base classes are *not* interfaces. They are *implementations*.

Comment: @Fareanor For example, I want both the performance of static polymorphism and be able to use heterogeneous list when it needed.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I regard as CRTP as 1) a way to refer the type itself in the interface like typeclass and 2) static polymorphism for better performance.  What do i miss？

Comment: @StructSeeker Is dynamic polymorphism really slower in your case ? Did you profile it or is it speculation/an over-optimization attempt ?
Anyway, your code already fulfill your two requirements, [as you can see here](https://godbolt.org/z/M3sKWb9Gv).

Comment: But with the static polymorphism, you won't have dynamic resolution of the type, which means that for `IConnection<Socket> s{Socket{}};`, `s` will not be a `Socket` but a `IConnection<Socket>`. So you will never be able to call `Socket` specific members from `s`, for example if stored in a container of `Connection *` (except if you give a `Socket` directly). In other words, `Base * b = new Derived;`-like syntax really works only if `Base` is polymorphic (dynamic).

Comment: @Fareanor I can use `s.dispatch()->SocketMethod()`. But I am worried about the problem of slicing......

Comment: "for better performance" this one is a lie. Better performance compared to what? To dynamic polymorphism? They are not applicable in the same kind of situation so their performance cannot be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts when you inherit from `Connection`.
You defined `Connection` as an abstract class, meaning the compiler will generate a vtable and all those fun toys.
Things that expect a `Connection*` expect the vtable and such.
But at the same time, you want the `Connection` interface to sometimes be static. Which means the callers will have to change the way they call stuff. But those are two very distinct types with two very different calling conventions.
You can't have both under the same interface.\

What you can do is a templated `Connection` class that receives a type and assumes that that type has the functions you expect and calls them in functions with the same name. You won't be able to pass it to stuff that expects `Connection*generically`, but it might still suit your needs.

```
template <typename T>
class Connection {
public:
    Connection(T&& impl) : _impl(impl) {}
    std::string recv() { return _impl.recv(); }
    ... rest of your implementation...
private:
    T impl;
};
```

This way, if `foo` is an object that implements some interface that requires `recv()`, `Connection<foo>` will use the vtable and you'll have dynamic dispatch. If you construct a `Connection<bar>` where bar is a plain class that happens to have a `recv()` method, it will still work, and you'll get static dispatch.

Comment: `class Connection : public IConnection`? and as OP uses both, and you use different meaning, rewrite both too.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. If `Connection<T>`  inherited from `IConnection` that defines a virtual function `recv()`, calls to `Connection<T>::recv()` would be virtual calls that go through the vtable.

Comment: I understood your answer as: use `T` for non dynamic polymorphic, use `Connection<T>` for dynamic polymorphic, It is I'm wrong. My point is to have an example of static/dynamic polymorphic with your solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps I explained myself wrong. I meant pass any T you want, as long as it contains the functions you expect the interface to have. If `T` is a type that inherits from `Connection` (his definition of `Connection`, perhaps I should have named mine otherwise) then `Connection<T>` would call that, it would go through the vtable and all that fun. If he passes `T` that has a non-virtual function `recv` it would still work and the compiler would resolve the correct function at compile time.

Comment: Ok, you turn polymorphic class into member (dropping reference/pointer which would allow derived class), and so allows compiler to do devirtualization as optimization. The inverse of what I had in mind ;-)

Comment: That isn't what I meant. Let's say I have a templated class `bar`. It receives one template param, `T`.
My `bar` holds an instance of `T` as a member called `foo`. Maybe `T` is a polymorphic class, maybe it is just a standard, non-polymorphic class. It is a template parameter, so a new `class bar` is initialized for each type I pass it.
The class `bar` has one member function - `recv`. And all it does is `return foo.recv();`.
If `T` happens to be a polymorphic class and `recv` is a virutal function, this will result in a virtual call. Otherwise, it is just a standard function call.

Comment: I suggest to **edit** your answer (instead of using comment) with those clarification.